# Aligning Tex Inside A Macro In MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I wrote a macro in MathJax which converts any instance of `\intertext` in the \begin{align*} environment to convert into

```
\\
\text{Text goes here}
\\
```

with the text above being aligned to the left. The reason for writing this is because the website that I'm working on does not support the `\intertext` command. Right now my macros in MathJax looks like the following:

```
{
intertext: ['\\\\\begin{array}{ccc}\\text{#1}\&\&\\end{array}\\\',1]
}
```

which I'm trying to align it to the left. However the LaTex command `\left` is not supported and I tried using `displayAlign` [as used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691029/mathjax-left-align-on-render) but it didn't work.

Right now I'm using [this website as a Sandbox to test out code](http://www.krassotkin.com/toys/mathjax/) but when I try it out on the main website it doesn't render properly as seen in the picture below:
[image]

Are there any other options to align `\text` left in the `\begin{align*}` environment without using `\left`, `\intertext`, or `displayAlign`?

For those interested I originally posted this question [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328496/aligning-tex-inside-a-macro-in-mathjax)

Edit: I added a picture of the text I'm trying to render.

Comment: The fundamental problem seems to be that `\noalign` is not supported.

Comment: IIUC, in real LaTeX, `\intertext` drops out of math mode into text-mode. There's no equivalent of that in MathJax but it seems closing the surrounding environment and opening it again might be reasonable.

Comment: @AndrewSwann- I think so too, but I'm looking for a work-around or an equivalent method that would solve the problem....

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger- I tried that but MathJax doesn't render the formulas and text correctly- it just returns the raw code.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, doesn't [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455133/aligning-tex-inside-a-macro-in-mathjax#comment66809899_39455133) defeat the point of an `align`, since you can't align the parts before and after the closure?  (At least, that's what brought me here!)

Comment: @LSpice not really. align has many use cases to group equations with common alignment points, see https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, could you say [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455133/aligning-tex-inside-a-macro-in-mathjax#comment119465424_39455133)?  I am familiar with the package, or thought I was, but didn't know any way to align across different environments, like `\begin{align} a & = b \end{align} intertext \begin{align} c & = d \end{align}`.

Comment: @LSpice I was only trying to say that align's usefulness is not limited to intertext.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of alignment

```
\begin{split}
g_y(t) &= \frac{d}{dt}\ln\Bigl(A(t) f\bigl( x(t) \bigr) \Bigr)
\\
&=
\frac{d}{dt}\ln\Bigl(A(t)\Bigr) + \frac{d}{dt}\ln\Bigl( f\bigl( x(t) \bigr) \Bigr)
\\
&=
g_A(t) + \frac{\dot f\bigl( x(t) \bigr)}{f\bigl( x(t) \bigr)}
\\
&=
g_A(t) + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f_i\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\dot x_i(t)}{f\bigl( x(t) \bigr)} \qquad\text{(Chain Rule)}
\\
&=
g_A(t) + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f_i\bigl(x(t)\bigr)x_i(t)}{f\bigl( x(t) \bigr)}\frac{\dot x_i(t)}{x_i(t)}
\\
&=
g_A(t) + \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i(t) g_{x_i}(t),
\end{split}
```

and this is the result with MathJax

[image]

Comment: This is close, but I'm still at a loss on how to align the text inside \begin{split} to the left. When I plug in the following code into the Sandbox: 
`
\begin{align*}
g_y(t) &= \frac{d}{dt}\ln\Bigl(A(t) f\bigl( x(t) \bigr) \Bigr)
\\
\begin{split}
\text{These words}
\end{split}
\\
\frac{d}{dt}\ln\Bigl(A(t)\Bigr) + \frac{d}{dt}\ln\Bigl( f\bigl( x(t) \bigr) \Bigr)\\
\end{align*}
`
The words "These words" don't align to the left.